# Rviz Message filter dropping message with rosbag1

Tags: usb-cam, camera, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a bunch of rosbag1 bag files with images, velodyne point clouds, and radar point clouds. I've now attempted a couple different methods of playing rosbag1 files in rosbag2, such as `rosbag_v2` and `rosbags-convert`.

Both of which can run the bag files, sometimes with warnings like

`[WARN] [1631782330.814976392] [rosbag2_transport]: Ignoring a topic '/rosout', reason: Something went wrong loading the typesupport library for message type rosgraph_msgs/Log. Library could not be found..`

but the right topics get published.

Attempting to visualize any of the three (camera, lidar, or radar) results in rviz2 throwing a lot of

`[INFO] [1631782411.735610318] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'usb_cam' at time 1624791621.995 for reason 'Unknown'`

I'm not sure how to handle this?

**Note**: Using noetic and foxy on ubuntu 20.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386632/rviz-message-filter-dropping-message-with-rosbag1/) by [morten](https://answers.ros.org/users/84853/morten/) on ROS Answers with karma: 198 on 2021-09-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-09-16**:
You are missing the time stamp, you need to add it and I think it will work.

**Comment by [morten](https://answers.ros.org/users/84853/morten/) on 2021-09-16**:
I'm reading from a data file of past recordings, which has been used in ros1 implementations. I don't have the possibility of adding or changing the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In this case, the conversion utilizing `rosbags-convert` and then playing the bag file by `ros2 bag play /path/to/file.bag` works fine.

The problem was relating to the lack of some static transform publishers between the frames, e.g. `usb_cam`, which then resulted in the filter dropping effected messages.

Note: The warning regarding `/rosout` persists and doesn't seem to be relevant and/or signalling anything critical. Everything works as expected after sorting out the missing transforms.

---

Originally posted by [morten](https://answers.ros.org/users/84853/morten/) with karma: 198 on 2021-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1